# Call function in store.js from other js file in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I use Vuex (store my data in store.js). On mutation I have a method  'autoUpdateDb' :

store.js :

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Vue from "vue";
import { serv } from "./serviceMixin";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({

mutations: {
    autoUpdateDb(state, payload) {
        functionA();
    },        
},

actions: {}
```

});

When I call the "autoUpdateDb" function I got an error "(void 0) is undefined" .
The location of  "functionA()" in other js file - serviceMixin.js

serviceMixin.js :

```
 functionA(){
      console.log("Hello");
            }
```

How should I call the requested function?

Regards and Thanks

Comment: Please, don't truncate the code because it's relevant. You need to import it correctly. If you didn't, this needs to be fixed.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a module loader like webpack, you need to import the function inside your store.js

```
const {functionA} = require('./serviceMixin');
```

Then export *functionA*

```
function functionA(){
```

}

```
module.exports = {
    functionA
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let the first file be First.js and second file be Second.js and both of them be in same folder. The below code is of File First.js

```
export default function FunctionOne(){
    console.log("from file one")
}
```

Second.js

```
import FunctionOne from './First.js'
FunctionOne()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `serviceMixin.js` file you should define the function correctly by adding the `function` keyword and export it like :

```
 export function functionA(){
      console.log("Hello");
            }
```

then in your store file import it in the top and call it in the action :

```
import {functionA} from './serviceMixin'
... 
mutations: {
      autoUpdateDb(state, payload) {
       functionA();
    },
```